# Coding JSON from Firebase with different keys in Swift

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have a this JSON in my Firebase RealtimeDatabase:

```
{
  "users": {
    “vZxpxfRG9tNaZKruActA7KyEgwz2": {
      "avatar": "022",
      "friends": {
        "HCLnd41UluP27w1JjXiRK8RvUwt2": {
          "nickname": "randomNickname"
        },
        "RaZKru2jG97KyEgtN7w1JtAwzxfc": {
          "nickname": "randomNickname2"
        }
      },
      "username": "myUsername"
    }
  }
}
```

and I'm trying to encode/decode it to this User model:

```
struct User: Codable {
    let username: String
    let avatar: String
    let friends: [UserFriend]?
}

struct UserFriend: Codable {
    let nickname: String?
}
```

It can encode/decode successfully if friends is nil for the User object since I give the reference path like this:

```
let ref = Database.database(url: "{Firebase database URL}").reference().child("users/\(userID)")
```

But it fails to decode if friends attribute is not nil on database. I can't convert the data to a model in Swift.

I'm clearly doing something wrong, possibly on both Firebase data structure and encoding/decoding with Swift.

Should I change the JSON structure from key/value pairs to an array or should I do something with the Swift to successfully convert the JSON objects to my custom Swift "UserFriend" object?

Comment: `Friends` isn't an array in your data, its a dict `[UUID : UserFriend]` You'll need to provide [CodingKeys](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) to take only the `Friends.values` if you want an array

Answer (score 1):

You can write a property wrapper that only extracts the values of the JSON dictionary/object, and ignores the keys that are random strings.

```
@propertyWrapper
struct DictionaryValue<T: Codable>: Codable {
    let wrappedValue: [T]
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        // here I decode the json as a dictionary, but keep only the values
        let dict = try [String: T](from: decoder)
        wrappedValue = Array(dict.values)
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        // you can only encode it this way,
        // since the keys are gone.
        // Consider only conforming to Decodable instead.
        try wrappedValue.encode(to: encoder)
    }
}
```

Then you can apply this to both the `users` key at the root, and the `friends` key:

```
struct Root: Codable {
    @DictionaryValue var users: [User]
}
struct User: Codable {
    let username: String
    let avatar: String
    @DictionaryValue var friends: [UserFriend]
}

struct UserFriend: Codable {
    let nickname: String?
}

let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: json)
print(root)
```

Note that since a dictionary is not ordered, the order of the friends and users might be different from the order in the original JSON.

Also, I'm assuming that all the keys are present. If the `friends` key is totally absent in the JSON when there are no friends, you would need to decode all the keys manually:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    var container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    username = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .username)
    avatar = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .avatar)
    if let friends = try container.decodeIfPresent([String: UserFriend].self, forKey: .friends)?.values {
        self.friends = Array(friends)
    }
}
```

Or explicitly write a property of type `DictionaryValue<UserFriend>?` (as a result, *not* using the property wrapper as a property wrapper) like this:

```
let _friends: DictionaryValue<UserFriend>?

var friends: [UserFriend]? {
    friendsWrapper?.wrappedValue
}
```